# Login Into Facebook Curl PHP

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I want to login into Facebook using URL and change curl header IP to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. but IP not change please tell me how to fix this.

```
  $ipku = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $ip = array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ipku", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ipku");

$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://m.facebook.com/login.php');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($em).'&pass='.urlencode($pa).'&login=Login');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

 curl_setopt($chs,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$ip);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/6.5.27309/34.1445; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10');

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,
   "https://www.facebook.com");

    $body = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: logging into facebook with curl is actually very difficult. took me several days to find a way to do it. its open source tho, you can have a look here https://github.com/divinity76/msgme/blob/master/src/php/relays/facebook.relay.php

Comment: Do not try to scrape Facebook. It is not allowed by their scraping policy. Use the API. It has everything that is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

and also, you have typo in line #15 so make this change:

```
// curl_setopt($chs,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $ip);
```

Comment: Any solution please

Comment: @kuwa If you want to access [m.facebook.com/checkpoint](http://m.facebook.com/checkpoint) after logging in with first code sample then just make another curl request with same options but using same cookies file otherwise you wont be logged in.